# HTML file shows gibberish characters

Tags: php, html

I'd appreciate if something can give me some input on what to do here. I'm using Ubuntu and I'm using Geany text editor. The HTML code is:

```
<form action=”processorder.php” method=”post”>
<table border=”0”>
<tr bgcolor=”#cccccc”>
<td width=”150”>Item</td>
<td width=”15”>Quantity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tires</td>
<td align=”center”><input type=”text” name=”tireqty” size=”3”
maxlength=”3” /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Oil</td>
<td align=”center”><input type=”text” name=”oilqty” size=”3”
maxlength=”3” /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spark Plugs</td>
<td align=”center”><input type=”text” name=”sparkqty” size=”3”
maxlength=”3” /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=”2” align=”center”><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When I run the HTML file this is what it shows:

```
<form action=â€processorder.phpâ€ method=â€postâ€>
<table border=â€0â€>
<tr bgcolor=â€#ccccccâ€>
<td width=â€150â€>Item</td>
<td width=â€15â€>Quantity</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tires</td>
<td align=â€centerâ€><input type=â€textâ€ name=â€tireqtyâ€ size=â€3â€
maxlength=â€3â€ /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Oil</td>
<td align=â€centerâ€><input type=â€textâ€ name=â€oilqtyâ€ size=â€3â€
maxlength=â€3â€ /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spark Plugs</td>
<td align=â€centerâ€><input type=â€textâ€ name=â€sparkqtyâ€ size=â€3â€
maxlength=â€3â€ /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=â€2â€ align=â€centerâ€><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Is there something wrong I am not seeing? And this piece of code is from a book I am currently reading.

Comment: using styling attributes like `align`, `bgcolor` and `width` is considered bad design nowadays. Separate content (HTML), functionality (Javascript) and Style (CSS). Using a table for layout-purpose (but non-tabular data) is considered bad for the same reason.

Comment: That's a good point, but it seems like the beginner-level documentation that is being used has not covered that yet. I'd let it alone until the OP is more comfortable with HTML in general.

Comment: @BlueIce IMHO as a teacher, there is no need to learn legacy coding before starting with the modern approach. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong kind of quotation marks.

`”` and `"` are very different. By using `"`, the code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `”`a re curly. Thats a different character then `"` (the one you should use). As `”` is a NON-ASCII character, it  is displayed differently in the browser if it doesn't get the correct encoding the server used. If you send the right encoding, it will display as `”`, but it's still no valid HTML then.